# Mongoid Observer for a specific field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

In the model, I know you can assign callbacks to specific fields (i.e. `value1`), like this:

```
after_save :run_callback_1, :if => :value1_changed?
```

Can this happen in the Observer so it's called if `user.value1` is changed? Or if `value1` of multiple models have changed?

```
class UserObserver < Mongoid::Observer

  def after_save(record)
    logger.debug "HERE"
  end

end
```